# How to call createDeleteForm in CRUD controller for another entity

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller

I have a basic CRUD controller using the "php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud AppBundle:Product" command. So I have the basic generated productController.php along with a Product.php entity that I made before, the generated CRUD product views, etc.

In ProductController.php there is a showAction method that has this line:
$deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($product);

I am trying to create a settings controller that embeds the product's showAction method but, as you can guess, trying to use
$this->createDeleteForm($product) yields

"Attempted to call an undefined method named "createDeleteForm" of class "AppBundle\Controller\SettingsController""

What's the best way to incorporate a settings controller and, if I'm on the right track, how can I generate the delete form for the product within the settings controller?

Thanks so much for any help you can offer!

Comment: You can copy this method to new controller

Comment: Uhg I feel like an idiot... guess I was tired. You are 100% correct. Turns out at the bottom of the generated products controller there IS a createDeleteForm method that got created 8-|.